# How to implement in erlang

Tags: erlang

I was thinking of using a list to store elements(files)

How do i change the code below so that it would lock one process(user) from accessing one file(element in list), while allowing another process(user) to access the file.

```
-module(bank).
-export([account/1, start/0, stop/0, deposit/1, get_bal/0, set_bal/1]).

account(Balance) ->
    receive
        {set, NewBalance} ->
            account(NewBalance);
        {get, From} ->
            From ! {balance, Balance},
            account(Balance);
        stop -> ok
    end.

start() ->
    Account_PID = spawn(bank, account, [0]),
    register(account_process, Account_PID).

stop() ->
    account_process ! stop,
    unregister(account_process).

set_bal(B) ->
    account_process ! {set, B}.

get_bal() ->
    account_process ! {get, self()},
    receive
        {balance, B} -> B
    end.

deposit(Amount) ->
    OldBalance = get_bal(),
    NewBalance = OldBalance + Amount,
    set_bal(NewBalance).
```

and

```
-module(banktest).
-export([start/0, client/1]).

start() ->
    bank:start(),
    mutex:start(),
    register(tester_process, self()),
    loop(10, 20, 100),
    unregister(tester_process),
    mutex:stop(),
    bank:stop().

loop(_, _, 0) ->
    true;
loop(Amount1, Amount2, N) ->
    bank:set_bal(0),
    spawn(banktest, client, [Amount1]),
    spawn(banktest, client, [Amount2]),
    receive
        done -> true
    end,
    receive
        done -> true
    end,
    io:format("Expected balance = ~B, actual balance = ~B~n~n",
              [Amount1 + Amount2, bank:get_bal()]),
    loop(Amount1, Amount2, N-1).

client(Amount) ->
    bank:deposit(Amount),
    tester_process ! done.
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'representing one variable as a file'? And when this list of variables would be stored?

Comment: i mean element, not variable

Answer (score 0):

If you want to serialize write calls but allow read ones, you can change the code as follow:

```
account(Balance, WriteLocker) ->
  receive
    free_lock ->
      account(Balance, undefined),
    {set, NewBalance, Caller} when WriteLocker =:= undefined ->
      Caller ! done,
      account(NewBalance, Caller),
    {get, From} ->
      From ! {balance, Balance},
      account(Balance, WriteLocker);
    stop -> ok
  end.

wait() ->
  receive
    {done, WriteLock} -> WriteLock ! free_lock.
  end.

set_bal(B) ->
  account_process ! {set, B, self()},
  wait().
```

If you want to lock reader too, add the guard to `{get, From}` message too.

Comment: i want to serialize both, could you modify the code i submitted so that it allows the code you used

Answer (score 0):

OK, still not quite understand the question but I will try to clarify and then propose a solution based on that:

1. You want to manage access to a set of files rather than a bank account
2. You want one user to have a write access to a file while other uses still have a read access to that file

If that's what you want then you can simply treat each file similarly to a bank account. It means that you should start one process (analogous to the code in the bank module) per file. In other words:

- for 1 bank account you need 1 process
- for 3 bank accounts you need 3 processes
- for 10 files you need 10 processes

Implementation details would depend on how you plan to manage the files on the server, but in the simplistic scenario the process could work analogously to the existing code:

```
file(FileName) ->
    receive
        {write, From, Data} ->
            ok = file:write_file(FileName, Data),
            From ! ok,
            file(FileName);
        {read, From} ->
            {ok, Data} = file:read_file(FileName), 
            From ! Data,
            file(FileName);
        stop -> ok
    end.

start() ->
    File_PID = spawn(file, file, ["somefile.txt"]),
    register(file_process, File_PID).
```

Comment: So would i just add this to the 'bank' module and it will work?

Comment: Not quite, the `file` function is just an example how the `account` function could be rewritten to update a file in a transaction similarly to updating an account in a transaction. You would need to update the other functions, i.e. instead of `set_bal` and `get_bal` you would have `write_file` and `read_file`, and so on. Also, as I mentioned, you would need one process per file and manage the processes with a supervisor. Besides that, this is not a very practical example because files are usually read/written asynchronously in batches (e.g. using file:read/2 and file:write/2)...

Comment: ... continuing, so this was more to point you to the right direction than to give you a ready-made answer. You would need to provide more detailed requirements regarding the API the application should provide for a more complete answer.

Comment: Thanks, i appreciate that! if i add the mutex module to the code above, would that help?

Comment: it doesn't have to work for now, just focusing on the mutex for now. I just need to figure out how to prevent another user from reading or writing to a file, whilst another user is currently using it

Comment: okay i understand now. My supervisor is the mutex.erl file that i have, and i just replace the get_bal and set_bal to relate to files, and replace the 'account(balance)' with 'file(FileName)'

Comment: As I mentioned, you would need one mutex per file you want to guard access to. If speaking just about one file for now, then yes, you are right, you would replace the `account` function with the `file` function from my example, amend the `get_bal` and `set_bal` function to work with files and you are done. Only one user can write to a file. However, as I also mentioned, this is very simplistic because files are usually written in batches, not the whole file at once. So this is a starting point for a more complete system.

Comment: just to clarify, is the code representing two users as a process each, and a file as another process?

Comment: It's just like with the account. One process is guarding access to one file. But I don't know what you actually want to implement, i.e. a real application or a model. Because the API to read/write file has to be called from somewhere, so it may well be that there will be another process representing a user that will be doing the actual calls. Are you trying to implement a real application that will work like Dropbox or just trying to learn how to guard access to a file?